# printing out the http path of of the show controller method & rendering it in a separate view - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, erb

I have a simple app called wishlists. The logic of the app is as follows:

1. User Enters the homepage
2. User can either start a new wishlist || view his wishlists
3. When the user clicks on start a new wishlist the user is brought to a separate view where he enters the name of the wishlist & submits the name.

Instead of the user entering the show view of the wishlist he just created, I just want to print the http path of the show controller method (/wishlists/:id(.:format) & render it in a separate view (which I will later use in a pop-up when I start buidling the front-end of the application)

This is a video of my app:

https://www.loom.com/share/290bba06128a4cb18fcf5fa9d6839728

Below is my controller methods

```html
class WishlistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_wishlist, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  
  # GET /home
  def home 
  end 
  
  # GET /wishlists
  def index
    @wishlists = Wishlist.all
  end

  # GET /wishlists/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /wishlists/new
  def new
    @wishlist = Wishlist.new
  end

  # GET /wishlists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /wishlists
  def create
    @wishlist = Wishlist.new(wishlist_params)

    if @wishlist.save
       redirect_to @wishlist, notice: "Wishlist was successfully created."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /wishlists/1
  def update
    if @wishlist.update(wishlist_params)
      redirect_to @wishlist, notice: "Wishlist was successfully updated."
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /wishlists/1
  def destroy
    @wishlist.destroy
    redirect_to wishlists_url, notice: "Wishlist was successfully destroyed."
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_wishlist
      @wishlist = Wishlist.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def wishlist_params
      params.require(:wishlist).permit(:name, :wishlist_link)
    end
end
```

This is my _form.html.erb view.

```html
<%= form_with(model: wishlist) do |form| %>
  <% if wishlist.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(wishlist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this wishlist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% wishlist.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And Finally this is my new.html.erb view:

```html
<h1>New wishlist</h1>

<%= render "form", wishlist: @wishlist %>

<br>


<div>
  <%= link_to "Back to homepage", root_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: You're thinking about this backwards. A controller doesn't actually have a HTTP path. It has a arbitrary number of potential routes that point to it. What you're looking for is most likely the routing helper such as `wishlist_path(wishlist)`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Actually I was able to do it at the end. Thanks alot for helping anyways!